# Finding Row Number of a Special Value in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula to find Row Number of Maximum value of a date within an array. For Example Maximum value of 2019.07.15 is 1417.15 and it's Row number is 4.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel does not read 2019.07.15 as a date. If you can change this to 2019/07/15 or 2019-07-15, you can use the following formula:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,MAX(A:A))
```

> This assumes the following:
>
> - column A is 'Date'
> - column B is 'Value 1'